# Why does Spark Dataset.map require all parts of the query to be serializable?

Tags: apache-spark, notserializableexception

I would like to use the Dataset.map function to transform the rows of my dataset. The sample looks like this:

```
val result = testRepository.readTable(db, tableName)
  .map(testInstance.doSomeOperation)
  .count()
```

where `testInstance` is a class that extends `java.io.Serializable`, but `testRepository` does extend this. The code throws the following error:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure.
Caused by: NotSerializableException: TestRepository
```

**Question**

I understand why `testInstance.doSomeOperation` needs to be serializable, since it's inside the map and will be distributed to the Spark workers. But why does `testRepository` needs to be serialized? I don't see why that is necessary for the map. Changing the definition to `class TestRepository extends java.io.Serializable`  solves the issue, but that is not desirable in the larger context of the project.

Is there a way to make this work without making TestRepository serializable, or why is it required to be serializable?

**Minimal working example**

Here's a full example with the code from both classes that reproduces the NotSerializableException:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class MyTableSchema(id: String, key: String, value: Double)
val db = "temp_autodelete"
val tableName = "serialization_test"

class TestRepository extends java.io.Serializable {
  def readTable(database: String, tableName: String): Dataset[MyTableSchema] = {
    spark.table(f"$database.$tableName")
    .as[MyTableSchema]
  }
}

val testRepository = new TestRepository()

class TestClass() extends java.io.Serializable {
  def doSomeOperation(row: MyTableSchema): MyTableSchema = {
  row 
  }
}

val testInstance = new TestClass()

val result = testRepository.readTable(db, tableName)
  .map(testInstance.doSomeOperation)
  .count()
```

Comment: Try with `object TestRepository`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would work in this example, but is impractical outside of this simplified example. The main question I'm trying to get to is why it needs to be serialized in the first place? Shouldn't only the code that goes into the `.map()` have to be serialized?

Comment: It's a fair question, but I have no answer to it. sorry

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because your `map` operation is reading from something that already takes place on the executors.

If you look at your pipeline:

```
val result = testRepository.readTable(db, tableName)
  .map(testInstance.doSomeOperation)
  .count()
```

The first thing you do is `testRepository.readTable(db, tableName)`. If we look inside of the `readTable` method, we see that you are doing a `spark.table` operation in there. If we look at the function signature of this method from the [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#table(tableName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame), we see the following function signature:

```
def table(tableName: String): DataFrame
```

This is not an operation that solely takes place on the driver (imagine reading in a file of >1TB while only taking place on the driver), and it creates a Dataframe (which is by itself a distributed dataset). That means that the `testRepository.readTable(db, tableName)` function needs to be distributed, and so your `testRepository` object needs to be distributed.

Hope this helps you!